# Can you upload a big email database to use as the sample for your Google Form survey?

Tags: google-forms

I am trying to put together a survey in Google Forms. This is will be emailed to a sample of 3000 people. Is there an easy way to import this email data set as a CSV file and send the emails out to the potential respondents?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

No, we can't upload a big email database to Google Forms.

## Explanation

Google Forms doesn't include a built-in database of email addresses. It could pull email addresses from Google Contacts but it's very unlikely that it will be possible to send a survey from Google Forms to such number of respondents.

One alternative is to create a group on Google Groups but it will not allow you to upload the 3000 email addresses at once maybe you could add 100 by day.

The solution will be to use mass email service to send the link to your form.